# Use VBA with the Word FormatFont dialog to change Content Control text name

Tags: vba, ms-word, dialog, contentcontrol

I have been trying various ways to allow a user to easily update the text font name in a couple of Word Content Controls on a contract template.  There is a form that is used to edit the control's text which can have a command button to run the procedure. I would like to make it easy and isolate the user from the Content Controls which are delicate things ;)

This is what I would like to do (I have tried many permutations of this code):

```
Dim dlg As Dialog

' Initialize the dialog

Set dlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFormatFont)

' Open the font dialog

dlg.Show

' Set the contentcontrols' text font name to the chosen one from the font dialog
ThisDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Font.Name = Dialogs(wdDialogFormatFont).Font.Name
```

Comment: And exactly how is the code not working for you?

Comment: If I use the code above I get a 424 error "Object Required". Probably because the property ".Font.Name" is not valid for the wdDialogFormatFont dialog. The dialog box opens, but how do I get the return values...if any?

Comment: «Content Controls which are delicate things» not if you apply the appropriate content control protections...

Comment: Two things: 1) Search in the Internet for Word Built-in Dialogbox arguments to check for the name of the font. I think it may be right, but you should check the listing. 2) Use `dlg`, the same as for `Show`in the line above, to reference the dialog on the right side of the equation so that it uses the same object as the user interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dlg.Show` use `dlg.Display`. The `Show` method combines both `Display` and `Execute`, so you won’t be able to get the chosen font to apply.

See the [VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.dialog.display) for further info.

Edit:

```
'check that the user pressed OK
If dlg.Display = -1 Then
  MsgBox dlg.Font
End If
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but how do you capture the return value..."MsgBox Dialogs(wdDialogFormatFont)" displays a number.

Comment: You need to be consistent and use dlg.

Answer (score 0):

This works...I recorded a macro to get the answer. Sorry I bothered you all:

```
Set dlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFormatFont)

' Open the font dialog

dlg.Show

' Show the selected font name

MsgBox Selection.Font.Name
```

...any font attribute from the font dialog can be gleaned from the .Font property and then applied to whatever text you wish ;-)